# Fail to import org.slf4j.Logger- how to add the jar to classpath?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, log4j, dependencies

I am learning to use Maven and Log4J. In the POM file I've added the below dependencies:

```
  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
       <version>1.7.12</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>log4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.17</version>
     </dependency>   
  </dependencies>
```

When I tried to import `import org.slf4j.Logger` in my main class, Eclipse says "The import org.slf4j cannot be resolved". I searched a while for an solution, and it seems that I need to download the distribution file here http://www.slf4j.org/download.html and "add the jar to the classpath"? I am confused: wouldn't Maven download that automatically? How can I "add the jar to the classpath"? I am a real beginner here. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Right click on your project folder->build path->configure build path->under the library tab click on (add external jar)->apply

Comment: @hermit that's not how you add dependencies in a mavenized project, any manual library configuration will be removed again upon syncing project settings when those dependencies are not in the pom configuration.

Comment: Did you run *mvn clean install* ?, after this what jars did you find are downloaded in local maven repository, forget about eclipse for now.

Answer (score 9):

As I had run to very similar issue, I write what my problem was:

I copied a wrong maven dependency from the internet (example).
It was only in test scope.. Oh Dear..

```
<scope>test</scope>
```

So after remove scope test section started to work as expected. :)

Comment: I bet you were following the example in https://www.baeldung.com/logback, and I was experiencing the same thing and spent quite some time to figure it out.

Comment: Thank you. I found your answer, and I actually had scope:test... *Oh, dear!* is the least I could think of.

Comment: Same problem again with `<scope>test</scope>`, but it's how it's given at [Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.7.30). After removing the line, it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You said you are new to Maven and have added the dependency in POM.
Now I am assuming that, you are assuming that, just because you added something in *pom.xml*, the dependent jars will be available for build.

Maven does not work that way. It points to a common repository from where you have to download the dependent jars (which happens when you do an *mvn install*)

After you mvn install works fine, you may use this src to setup in your eclipse IDE either by using *mvn eclipse:eclipse* or using an eclipse maven plugin.

So, after you added the dependency, run following command from where your project is located

```
mvn clean install;
```

Your jars should be downloaded from maven to your local directory something like:

> C:\Users\user.m2\repository

Comment: As he has written he does not use cmd, but eclipse. 
IDE should pick it up, and never ever he should do mvn eclipse:eclipse if project is seen as maven project by eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You also need dependency to `slf4j-api`

Also, if you use eclipse, it might be the case - try to update project.

Comment: You are correct, but the slf4j-log4j12 dependency should transitively be adding the missing api dependency already. The fact that this is not happening is a clear sign there may be more wrong with the pom setup than is being shown here.

Comment: @szefuf Thanks. I had updated the project. I added ` <dependency> 
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> 
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId> 
  <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>` but it still doesn't work..

Comment: Did you try to build your project from terminal? Do you have the error then?

Comment: @szefuf the project was ok before log4j. Since I can't import org.slf4j.Logger and create a method, I am not sure how to test it from cmd..

Comment: I'm not an expert on log4j as I do not use it, but I'm not sure you should have dependency to log4j in your pom.xml. Try slf4j-log4j12 only. If I'm wrong, I hope somebody will correct me.

Answer (score 0):

****** It's working for me.****

Just add below dependencyin pom.xml under dependencies

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-jcl</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>     
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```